# Bug with accessing XML data named "duration" Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, duration

Is there any reason why something named `duration` wouldn't work in JQuery?
For example, here is my XML

```
<video description="description etc" duration="43306" id="1144537378001" name="Fashion" thumbnail="http://www.domain.com/1144537378001-219x119.jpg" videoURL="http://www.domain.com/Half.mp4" videoId="1144537378001"/>

alert($(this).attr("duration"));
alert($(this).attr("thumbnail"));
alert($(this).attr("id"));
```

Everything will alert ok, except duration will always be NaN despite being fine in the XML. Even before I do parseInt or eval.

I can't change the XML so any workarounds using JS would be awesome.

Comment: I don't want to, vague idea at getting it to work

Answer (score 0):

works like a dream

http://jsfiddle.net/QevjN/

(its not [json](http://www.json.org/) data btw)

Comment: Thanks for linking to JSfiddle - really handy.

Comment: Woops, was JSON originally but I changed it. Edited now

Answer (score 0):

Dodn't know what the issue could be, but you can always try with plain JavaScript dom methods.

```
document.getElementById("1144537378001").getAttribute("duration");
```

If it still doesn't work then you can assume that it's not jQuery related.